# I am writing slides. I want to explain how it works. and I should write how does it work or how it works as the title of one slide?

Tags: grammar, writing

I am not sure which one I should use, please help me.
**How it works?**
**How does it work?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Either is a suitable title, but only "how *does* it work" is a question to be written with a question mark.

- How it works
- How does it work?

"How does it work?" as a title before an explanation of how something actually works is a form of *rhetorical question*. Many people find a question as a title grabs attention as it makes clear the question you are *going to answer*. Although in my opinion, "How it works" makes it just as clear what you are going to discuss next. It really is a matter of personal choice.